# Why does indexing a dataframe column return two values after concatenating two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

When I index a column I receive two results. I haven't encountered this before when concatenating dataframes. Why did this happen and how can I avoid this?

```
analystRatingsRaw = dfList[1]
partnerHeadlinesRaw = dfList[2]
news = pd.concat([analystRatingsRaw, partnerHeadlinesRaw])

news.date[0]

Output:
0    2020-06-05 10:30:54-04:00
0          2020-06-01 00:00:00
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `ignore_index=True` parameter to pd.concat to get the combined dataframe to get the default range index.

Otherwise, you are just concatenating the dataframes with their current indexing hence you have two 0 labeled indexes.

Or you can use `iloc`, this `news.iloc[0, news.columns.get_loc('date')]`.